# Current Field Value to a VBA String Programmatically

Tags: ms-access, vba

I need to take the current value of a field from the record displayed on an Access form and put that text into a VBA string programmatically. This seems so simple but I have not yet been to find any guidance from either an aftermarket Access 2013 text I purchased or the Internet and I have tried everything I can think of with no success whatsoever, Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
dim strYourString as string

strYourString = forms![Your Form Name].[Field Name].Value
```

And you're done!